# Dual boot screen issue: windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, screen

After starting windows 10 in dual boot, screen looks like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rG6u1r0GfFxYgbhHm8plKR3bMfEJFSie/view?usp=drivesdk

I have dual boot of windows 10 and Ubuntu. Ubuntu works fine. Problem starts when Windows is started, as shown in screenshot screen goes way up and mouse can move only till end of taskbar visible. What to do, help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an issue with the resolution of windows 10. 
As half the screen is occupied by the taskbar the resolution may have mismatched.
 One possible solution is to open display properties(right click desktop > properties), goto settings check if the resolution has been set to 640*480 or 800*600, if so change it to 1024*768(the most commonly used resolution).
If its not possible, try removing and re-installing the OS.

Comment: Upper part windows 10, next part from Ubuntu, rest blank black or pixelated as in image attachment, tried reinstalling windows another 3 pc but same. Not possible to see properties menu windows, so no use of right click.